# What are the key advantages and use cases of RDF* graphs compared to LPG?

Tags: graph, rdf, turtle-rdf, rdf-star

I understand that RDF* solves the issue of properties and attributes and internal structure missing in RDF. But I wonder what are some use cases when RDF* are better than LPG? And what are the main advantages of RDF* over LPGs?

Comment: In LPG, edges can have attributes which values are of primitive types only. In RDF*, "edges" can also have attributes which values are other "nodes" or even "edges". Examples are `<<:Alice :likes :Bob>> :isSaidBy :Carol` or `:Carol :says <<:Alice :likes :Bob>>`.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple use cases that, with the introduction of the RDF* (RDF Star) framework, RDF* can compete with LPG applications according to this [OpenCredo blog](https://opencredo.com/blogs/making-sense-of-data-with-rdf-vs-lpg/).

- Data Provenance (Lineage)
- Representing Temporal Dimension
- Data Analytics

Being *able* to serve as a framework to support a use case does not alone merit an "advantage", but it does introduce the benefits that RDF already had to a new use case.

(I am answering under the assumption that you are distinguishing the existing use cases where RDF (without *) was already more ideal than LPG, from the use cases that were better suited for LPG before the introduction of RDF Star. This is why I omitted "Application with Cross-Domain Knowledge" from the above list since that use case was merely enhanced as an even better RDF choice.)

Comment: This is more about the advantages of RDF* over RDF though? Going from the article you linked... Data Provenance: tldr - now possible because you can put info in edges. Data Analytics: tldr - you can do analytics because you can put properties on edges. Temporal Dimension: tldr - now possible because you can put the data on the node/edge. These aren't what I would exactly call "advantages" or reasons to use RDF over LPG. These are advantages of using RDF* over RDF

Comment: So, you're saying, just being possible doesn't merit "advantage". Gotcha. I'll adjust my language to merely state these as new possibilities, rather than claiming them as better.

Comment: Only because the question is specific about advantages of one over the other. Personally, I think what you list are important considerations :)